# Passing object by using ViewDataDictionary instance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got one small doubt,that is the following method adds object to ViewData Model property.

```
  public ActionResult StronglyTypedView()
  {
            var obj = new MvcRouting.Models.Student();
            obj.age = 24;
            obj.name = "prab";
            ViewData.Model = obj;           
            return View();
  }
```

`ViewData property` return type in `ViewDataDictionary`.So i created instance of `ViewDataDictionary` and assigned object to `Model` property.But its not working,how to solve this?

```
public ActionResult StronglyTypedView()
{
   var obj = new MvcRouting.Models.Student();
   obj.age = 24;
   obj.name = "prab";
   var DicObj = new ViewDataDictionary();
   DicObj.Model = obj;
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Why you just don't pass the model to the View `return View(obj)`?

Comment: ya i know that but i want to know .is possible to do by using ViewDataDictionary instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest doing so, but you can return the `ViewResult` directly from the action:

```
public ActionResult StronglyTypedView()
{
    var obj = new MvcRouting.Models.Student();
    obj.age = 24;
    obj.name = "prab";
    var DicObj = new ViewDataDictionary();
    DicObj.Model = obj;
    return new ViewResult
               {
                   ViewData = DicObj
               };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your action like the following:

```
public ActionResult StronglyTypedView()
{
        var obj = new MvcRouting.Models.Student();
        obj.age = 24;
        obj.name = "prab";
        ViewData["Model"] = obj;           
        return View();
}
```

and in your view, something like this:

```
<div>@((MvcRouting.Models.Student)ViewData["Model"].name)</div>
```